# Apollo Angular Graphql, How to use multiple enpoints?

Tags: angularjs, angular, graphql, apollo

```
 mydomain.com/graphql/tags

mydomain.com/graphql/user

 mydomain.com/graphql/friend
```

I've a server with graphql enpoints like this, each has it's own mutations and queries, how can i make a angular front end for it? I've searched a bit, but every tutorial shows how i can use a single graphql server on apollo client. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/composition/

Comment: or maybe this 
https://medium.com/open-graphql/apollo-multiple-clients-with-react-b34b571210a5

Comment: or this https://www.loudnoises.us/next-js-two-apollo-clients-two-graphql-data-sources-the-easy-way/

if you found a working solution share it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a named client for each endpoint: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/multiple-clients/

`apollo.create(options, 'tags');`

`apollo.create(options, 'user');`

`apollo.create(options, 'friend');`

Then, you can specify which client to use when querying:

`apollo.use('tags').watchQuery({...});`